# How do I connect this display to an Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

I am completely new to this, and a novice when it comes to electronics but I want to learn.
Can someone pls tell me how I would connect the display in the photo here with an Arduino Uno (which I have ordered).  The plan is to interface my car with this transparent display to produce a form of HUD.
I have done some searching but to no avail so far, would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.
many thanks[image: transparent LCD clock]

Comment: What do you know about this display? Do you have a datasheet, a make/model, any information to go on? We really can't tell you much from a picture.

Comment: Thank you. Not yet but I will try to find out.  This was the only transparent display that I could find available for purchase.

Comment: Can can always scrap the electronics and [drive the LCD yourself](http://awawa.hariko.com/avr_lcd_drive_en.html). But you need quite a few IO pins, looking at that ribbon cable. Also it's not really a beginners project.

Comment: You don't need a transparent display. You can project a bright LED up to the windshield and it will be reflected in your line of sight, you will have to deal with projecting a flipped image so it appears correct to the observer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in for a *lot* of work. Everything on the PCB is useless to you, so you'd have to interface the raw panel to the Arduino.

The first matter is to remove the panel from the board. You will need to desolder all of the connections, and then solder either some sort of rigid connector or individual wires to the large ribbon connector. The only advice I can give you is "be prepared to fail".

Once you've done that, you will need to read [AVR340](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8103.pdf) in order to learn how to drive the panel. Note that the Uno itself does not have enough pins to drive the panel directly, so you will need to get an I/O expander or two for this.

Did I mention that you're in for a lot of work? Well, I'm mentioning it again. Good luck though.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it wouldn't be straightforward. This is the info I was looking for - somewhere to start.

Comment: @DrT Do you have an update on how the project went. I'm interested in whatever, even if it failed, as I learn a lot from HOW / WHY things fail.